# Unable to insert all rows into SQL table using python script

Tags: python, sql, json

I have two data sets in my JSON API. I am unable to insert both into SQL Server. The Iteration using for loop doesnt seem to pick up the second data. Can someone please help me understand how to fix this. this is new for me, so am not able to find out whats wrong since the coding is bit different from SQL

```
import urllib, json
import pyodbc


#read data from API
url = "http://nagiosdatagateway.vestas.net/esq/ITE1452552/logstash- 2018.12.16/2/desc"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

#define db connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                      "Server=DKCDCVDCP42\DPA;"
                      "Database=VPDC;"
                      "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
i = 0  
j = len(data)
print j
for i in range(i,j-1): 
#   print data[1]["_source"]["utc_timestamp"]
    print i
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_comment"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"]
    cursor.execute("insert into vpdc.pa.Pythontable(nagios_comment,nagios_author) values (?,?)",(data[i] 
    ["_source"]["nagios_comment"],data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"] ))
    i += 1
    print i
    cnxn.commit()
```

both these two sets of values should be in the SQL table for columns

Nagios_comment & Nagios_author
307262828  Alex Christopher Ramos
307160348  Alex Christopher Ramos

Comment: Please fix code indentation.

Comment: `i += 1` is not needed in the for loop. That's because `range(i, j-1)` returns an iterable object and for automatically iterates over it.

Comment: Also, the `i += 1` does not change the range generator.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In Python, indentation is significative (it's part of the languages syntax), so no one can help with your snippet's broken indentation. Please edit your post to fix the indentation so it __exactly__ matches your own code.

Comment: Yes, Thanks @brunodesthuilliers. when you mentioned about indentation, i tried again by indenting the cursor.execute statement. It was outside the loop before. I corrected it now and working perfectly fine.

Comment: @MaJoR : I removed I+=1 as you pointed out. Thanks. My script works well now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue had been resolved by correctly indenting the cursor.execute statement in the script as below. In my original script, there was no indentation done for this line.so it was called outside the loop

```
import urllib, json
import pyodbc


#read data from API
url = "http://nagiosdatagateway.vestas.net/esq/ITE1452552/logstash-2018.12.16/2/desc"
response = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

#define db connection
cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};"
                  "Server=DKCDCVDCP42\DPA;"
                  "Database=VPDC;"
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
i = 0  
j = len(data)
print j
for i in range(0,2): 
   #print data[1]["_source"]["utc_timestamp"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_comment"]
    print data[i]["_source"]["nagios_author"]
    cursor.execute("insert into vpdc.pa.Pythontable(nagios_comment,nagios_author) 
    values (?,?)",(data[i]["_source"]["nagios_comment"],data[i]["_source"] 
     ["nagios_author"] ))
cnxn.commit()
```